# How to handle Firebase FCM registration token if you have thousands of users for sending push notifications?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, android-push-notification

I want to send push notifications to thousands of mobile users. Do i need to store the registration tokens of all the users in my database ?
If so how can i store it efficiently while detecting the token changes and all ? I want to send push notifications for all the users whether they are logged in or not.

I am extracting token like this

```js
 await getToken(messaging, {
      vapidKey: 'vapid key',
    })
      .then((currentToken: any) => {
        if (currentToken) {
          console.log('toekn', currentToken)
          // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
        } else {
          // Show permission request UI
          console.log(
            'No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.',
          )
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err)
      })
```

Comment: Your map returns 'divs', they can't be filtered, they are not objects. Methods are executed one after the other when chained.

Comment: I don't think div is the issue here. It works when id is mapped to key inside div.  You can look at the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a react part and the rendere part does not contain an object for filtering.

Anyway it is a good idea to do the filtering first and then render the data set for output.

```
const
    weekLogs = this.props.weeklyLogs          
        .filter(weekLogs => weekLogs.id<10)  
        .map(weekLogs =>
            <div >
                <h3>{weekLogs.title}</h3>
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: then you got s/t to filter.

Comment: but anyway why filter at last?

Comment: Well its not mandatory. I just got the error that way and wanted to know why as i can't figure out myself.

Comment: you could take a console.log with the mapped array and have a look how it looks like. i assume it contains only the html part and no information from the original object.